# Baratza Encore is grinding too coarse

Tags: pour-over, grinder, chemex

Listing out details as I best know. I'm stuck on what might be wrong or if there is anything I can do.

- Purchased used Baratza Encore off Facebook Marketplace 2.5 months ago
- Been using grinder every single day, mainly for Chemex pourovers, in the 18-22 grind size range
- A couple days ago, noticed it was grinder very coarse in my usual range. Also, doesn't seem like much of a difference between 16 - 22
- I took the grinder apart to recalibrate the little screw. Moved it into the fine section to calibrate the grinder finer
- Same problem. No difference in grind between 16-22, haven't tried outside those ranges yet, and it's grinding very coarse, like french press or even cold brew size.

Any ideas on what I can do, or is it time for a new grinder? Thanks.

Comment: Have you not tried finer than 16? Any reason for not trying finer?

Comment: Yeah, I can go finer, but that doesn't address the fact that something has changed for the range I've been using :-(

Comment: Do try Baratza support: https://www.baratza.com/support/contact

Answer (score 2):

I have the grinder myself too, and from what I recall (haven't used it for a while) the number scale doesn't correspond with a specific grind size. I haven't taken it apart, but when I would thoroughly clean it (mostly taking out residue coffee dust with a vacuum cleaner), I think I had to set it a bit finer (maybe 2 or 3 on the number scale) to achieve the same results.

Seeing that you took the grinding mechanism itself apart as well, I wouldn't be surprised if the number scale is a bit further off compared to what you were used to.

To see if you can achieve the same grind size you used before, I'd simply grind finer until you get there. If you get down to the lowest setting and the grind isn't getting to the desired level (which you previously did get from the same machine) then there's probably a problem with the way the machine was reassembled.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a sudden problem with coarse grinding after I cleaned the unit, so it had to be my fault. Checking the Encore grinding issue video didn't help much. Before I'd get into burr re-calibration, sometimes the simplest fix is just to make sure the hopper is seated properly. I checked that the burr was set in properly with the orange tabs lined up, but my hopper had to be pushed down slightly with the white mark on it lined up with the setting on the far right. If your hopper is seated properly, when you turn it clockwise to a finer setting (it helps to push down with light pressure), the hopper should NOT pull out at that new finer setting. If it does, it wasn't seated properly, and you'll get a coarse grind, and the hopper may wobble a bit during grinding. Once I made sure it was down, and couldn't easily be pulled out, it ground just perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the exact same issue (except for the fact that I've had my grinder all along; got it about two and half years ago). I doubt that the problem stems from reassembly since it started grinding too coarsely before we calibrated it.

I happen to own a Flair and would occasionally grind the beans on the Encore if I was feeling too lazy to use the Comandante. The Encore could usually hit the espresso range somewhere between settings 3 and 4. To confirm my suspicions, I tried pulling a shot with some beans ground at setting 1 today... and the water went right through the espresso puck, no pressure needed. Bottom line: something is way off and, no matter the setting, I just can't seem to make the same adjustments that I could only two weeks ago. It's almost as if the burrs were stuck in the same position no matter where you set the dial.

Comment: Welcome to Coffee SE! Are you posting this to get some troubleshooting feedback? If so, I think it's better [asked as a new question](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). While I don't think the Encore is optimized for espresso, the question why it could get that fine before but not now is still interesting (especially after you ruled out reassembly). Your issue seems slightly different from this question because you are trying to get espresso grind size while this question considers issues with pour-over grind size.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for taking the time to reply! I actually finally figured out what the problem was thanks to Baratza's extremely helpful troubleshooting guides (https://baratza.com/troubleshooting/). I checked out the video for grind quality issues and then took a good look at my grinder. It turns out two of the burr flanges on the ring burr had broken off (who knows when). Without those little flanges (there should be three), you actually can't dial in any setting. In short, I've ordered a replacement for €7,50 and should be good to go when that arrives! :)